# Interrupt Controller's In-Service Register bits when a non-maskable interrupt occurs

Tags: x86, interrupt, isr

I have the following question (regarding `x86` architecture):

What happens when a non-maskable interrupt (e.g. `NMI`) interrupts a maskable interrupt which is in progress? Does the corresponding ISR (In-Service Register) flag of the pre-empted interrupt remains set in the interrupt controller's ISR register when the maskable interrupt is served or all the bits in the In-Service Register are getting cleared?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the original IBM PC hardware design, the NMI signal did not involve the interrupt controller in any way, so it would have no effect on the in-service register. Though it's some 30 years later, my guess is this is still the case; modern chip makers more or less have their hands tied by these kinds of core legacy behaviors.

Comment: I agree. NMI is an input to the core, while the In-Service Register is part of the APIC. In other words, the NMI bypasses the APIC entirely and should not affect the state of APIC registers.

Answer (score 0):

The ISR must be cleared in the interrupt handler by sending EOI command (end of interrupt) to the interrupt controller.

Comment: Hi! I know that but that's not what I am asking. I am asking **if** the bits in the In-Service register are affected **during the execution** of a non-maskable interrupt.